# Request error when using a PSKeyVaultCertificate to add authentication to an Azure Service Principal

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a working script that gets a certificate and assigns it to an Azure Service Principal for authentication:

```
    $rawData = $Certificate.Certificate.GetRawCertData()
    $base64Value = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($rawData)

    $hash = $Certificate.Certificate.GetCertHash()
    $base64Thumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hash)

    New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential `
            -ObjectId $app.ObjectId `
            -CustomKeyIdentifier $base64Thumbprint `
            -Type AsymmetricX509Cert `
            -Usage Verify `
            -Value $base64Value `
            -StartDate $Certificate.Created `
            -EndDate $Certificate.Certificate.NotAfter
```

After a module update, the model of the certificate received changed from [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.Models.**KeyVaultCertificate**] to the new [[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.Models.**PSKeyVaultCertificate**]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.keyvault.models.pskeyvaultcertificate?view=azurerm-ps) and now New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential returns this error:

```
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: When present, application key identifier cannot be empty and can be at most 32 bytes.
Parameter name: applicationKeyIdentifierValue
RequestId: 95338cec-c81f-436d-a692-e49784b3fd1a
DateTimeStamp: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 22:47:44 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

Thing is I can't find technical documentation of the old KeyVaultCertificate model to compare it to the new one and even in the [command doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationkeycredential?view=azureadps-2.0) the example given is a X509Certificate2 so I don't know what I'm missing

Comment: I think KeyVault store certificates directly as certificates.  I think using the ...Key... cmdlets is reserved for storing something like a password.  But I could be wrong there.   Start with New-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy and work forward from there.

Comment: I got this when the credential description was too long.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a good candidate for an issue on the azure-powershell github repo. Open up an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues